# Dynamically adding HTML using .innerHTML (formatting issue in IE7)

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, innerhtml

I have a select dropdown that when updated takes the new variable and dynamically updates the div directly below it.

HERE is my select input:

```
<select name='region_name' onchange='showDistrict(this.value)'>
```

here is my javascript that controls the dynamic stuff:

```
<script>
function showDistrict(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("district_div").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("district_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdistrict.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The page getdistrict.php?q=  does another MySQL call and loops out info into the div "district_div"  **MY PROBLEM IS... that div region does not stretch correctly in IE 7.** So my dynamic data overlays everything below it.

When I look at the source with firebug I don't even see the new html from innerHTML so I am not sure this is a css issue or something having to do with .innerHTML

Comment: What CSS have you given to the div?

Comment: as you explained it looks like a CSS issue... Just apply fixed width to div in pixel and check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not set any `width` or `height` for this DIV, or set only `min-width min-height`, and you can also set `overflow:hidden` for this DIV

Comment: I moved my CSS around a little but I also followed your instructions above and got it working. I will post my css when I have more time. Thanks for your help. +1 checked.